# Finding the direction vector of a tangent line given one point

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

I have read example in a math text book with the following problem:

The surface $z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{9-2x^2-y^2}$ and the plane $y=1$ intersect. Find parametric equation for a tangent line at $(\sqrt{2},1,2$)!

I know that the function $z$ is differentiated partially with respect to $x$ as $y$ is remained constant implying the slope of the tangent line at $(\sqrt{2},1,2)$, however what I am confused is that why the solution shows that the direction vector of the tangent line is $(1, 0, -\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Well, what do you think it is?

Comment: The direction vector determines each point coordinate of the tangent line, however, how does it come up with $(1,0,\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: No, not what you think a direction vector is in general. What do you think the specific direction vector for this tangent line is?

Comment: What specifically is confusing you about the example? If you update your question to include at least the parts of this example that you don’t understand, you’re much more likely to get some help with it.